# Probability distribution of a genetics problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let w be a string of $l$ zeros.

So, $a = 000000000000000\dots$

The ensemble at generation 0 is simply $n$ copies of $a$.

One gets the ensemble at generation $g$ by replication every single string in the ensemble at generation $g-1$.

A replication proceeds as follows.

The original string is retained. A copied string is made. The copied string has the same char as the original string. Each char in the copied string has a chance to be flipped. ($1 \to 0$, or $0 \to 1$). Flipping is done independently, and has a probability of $p <<1$.

After G generations, there shall be $n \cdot 2^G$ sequences.

There will be 1 unique sequence with 0 changes from a. This will have many copies.

There will be up to $l$ unique sequences with 1 difference. There will be some number of unique sequences with 2 differences. Etc, etc.

We shall order the unique sequences with 1 difference by how many copies they have. Same with the unique sequences with 2 differences.

What are the statistical properties of this order? As an example, what is the expected value of the $i$'th most prevalent unique sequence with one difference?